# How do I stream UDP raspivid over ipv6 from raspberry pi to my debian virtual machine mplayer

Tags: networking, debian, ipv6, raspbian, netcat

I can stream UDP raspivid to my host machine fine using ipv4 but my project needs to be able to stream over ipv6.

I tested my ipv6 connection via netcat-openbsd and I've confirmed my debian host machine can receive a connection over ipv6 with a (nc -l -6 -p 2222) so why doesnt the below work.

Host Machine

sudo nc -l -u -6 -p 2222 | mplayer -fps 200 -demuxer h264es -

raspberry pi

/opt/vc/bin/raspivid -t 0 -w 300 -h 300 -hf -fps 20 -o - | nc -v -u "(insert ipv6 here)" 2222

Comment: Real-time traffic should use UDP, not TCP. With TCP, when packets are lost (and they will be) you will be requesting out-of-date information, and waiting for it (not real time), that is useless by the time you get it.

Comment: I'll try that protocol out but im struggling trying to get my open virtualbox port to be detected do you think you can help with that as well?